# Google user-images near geocoordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, photo

We need to show images near a given location (lat/lng) in a web-application. The same pictures you see as when you go to maps.google.com and click "Photos" on the left side.

I have come up with that code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(mk) {

    var size = 200;
    var radius = 500000;

    var lng = marker.latLng.D;
    var lat = marker.latLng.k;

    var images = [];
    var request = {
        location : {
            lat : lat,
            lng : lng
        },
        radius : radius,
    };

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, loc) {
            var photos = loc.photos;
            if (photos) {
                for (var i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
                    images.push(photos[i].getUrl({
                        'maxWidth' : size,
                        'maxHeight' : size
                    }));
                }
            }
        });

        console.log(images);

    });
});
```

Unfortunately, the images are not the same as you would see in Google Maps - it's more like logos of restaurants & other places nearby. How can I retrieve the images like in the attached printscreen?

[image]

Comment: Can you post screenshot of how your photos look?

Comment: Most of the photos are content from panoramio or picasa, use their API's  to request the photos.

Comment: Panoramio API seems to be deprecated: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/panoramiolayer

Comment: What images do you get for that location? I get none. It's a bit vague right now as to what we are supposed to use. Panoramio is deprecated. Place Photos doesn't seem to return the same pictures. PhotoSphere doesn't seem to allow for location based searches... Anyone who can shed some light on this is welcome to post here...

Comment: yeah that's because the places-API does return images of Google Places (restaurants, hotels etc) and not the images they display on Google Maps like in my printscreen...

Comment: It seems https://www.google.com/maps/views/home?gl=us is about to replace Panoramio and I've placed a tweet at the responsible person at Google... I'll come back if there's anything noteworthy

Answer (score -2):

Based off Dr.Molle comment, you can do 
[Class PhotoListWidget](http://www.panoramio.com/api/widget/reference.html#PhotoWidgetOptions) from

> A widget that shows multiple photos at a time. The 'setPosition'
>   method needs to be called for the widget to start displaying anything.
>   This lets the user install handlers for the PHOTO_CHANGED event after
>   the widget is constructed but before the event is raised. A photo list
>   widget contains several "slots" arranged in a grid. Each slot displays
>   a photo (or is empty). Slots are numbered from 0 to (rows * columns -
>   1). The 0th slot is in the upper-left corner. In a
>   horizontally-scrolling widget, the slots are ordered from top to
>   bottom in the inner loop, and from left to right in the outer loop; in
>   a vertically-scrolling widget, left-to-right in the inner loop and
>   top-to-bottom in the outer loop. Each slot has a position in the
>   result set, and displays the photo at that position. The slots'
>   positions increase as the slot number. The widget's "position" is the
>   position of its 0th slot. This extends panoramio.Widget.

Comment: Isn't Panoramio deprecated? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/panoramiolayer